# Find the limit : $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}^-}\frac{\sin^2x-\cos 2x-\frac{1}{2}}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}$

Tags: limits

> Find the limit :
>   $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}^-}\frac{\sin^2x-\cos 2x-\frac{1}{2}}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

My work.
$$x-\frac{\pi}{4}=u \to x=\frac{\pi}{4}+u$$

$$\cos 2(\frac{\pi}{4}+u)=\cos (\frac{\pi}{2}+2u)=-\sin 2u $$
So we have :
$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}^-}\frac{\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{4}+u)+\sin 2u-\frac{1}{2}}{u}.$$
Now what?

Comment: Use L'Hospital's rule

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Using $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x,$

$$\dfrac{2\sin^2x-2\cos2x-1}{2x-\dfrac\pi2}=\dfrac{-3\cos2x}{2x-\dfrac\pi2}$$

Set $2x-\dfrac\pi2=y$

Comment: let $f(x)=\sin^2x-\cos2 x$  then $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}^-}\frac{\sin^2x-\cos 2x-\frac{1}{2}}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}= f'_{-}(\frac{\pi}{4})$$
So :
$$f'(x)=2\sin x\cos x +2\sin 2x$$
thus :
$$f'(\frac{\pi}{4}) =3$$
it is right ?

Comment: @Almot1960, Right u r

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach,
\begin{align}\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}^-}\frac{\sin^2x-\cos 2x-\frac{1}{2}}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}&=\lim_{u \to 0^-}\frac{\sin^2(u+\pi/4)-\cos 2(u+\pi/4)-\frac{1}{2}}{u}\\
&=\lim_{u \to 0^-}\frac{\left(\frac{\sin(u)+\cos(u)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+\sin(2u)-\frac{1}{2}}{u}\\
&=\lim_{u \to 0^-}\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+u+o(u)\right)^2+2u+o(u)-\frac{1}{2}}{u}\\
&=\lim_{u \to 0^-}\frac{u+2u+o(u)}{u}=3
\end{align}
where we used the fact that $\sin(au)=au+o(u)$ as $u \to 0$.